# Openfire Kraken Plugin Facebook Transport not working

Tags: openfire

I have configured Openfire 3.6.4 with Kraken plugin for accessing GTalk, Yahoo, Facebook and MSN buddies. All are working fine except for Facebook.

I tried every versions of Kraken plugins which are available. In some cases, Facebook transport is showing means user gets login in Facebook but it is not getting buddy list. In other case, the transport doesn't get registered means user don't get logged in. (Credential not valid error)

I also checked Kraken Developer forum, but I didn't get exact solution.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download latest source of `Kraken` from its repository. and Build it. This will work for you.

For reference: http://kraken.blathersource.org/node/9

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility for some people. When you log into Openfire with Kraken plug-in, Facebook requires a vanity name for login, not your email address. So when you are logged into the Facebook site in the upper right corner, click on Account > Account Settings > Username and you will see:

http://www.facebook.com/ (and something after that)

e.g. john.doe1. This is the user name you use to log in.